# Comparing two columns to get value for third column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have problem comparing two columns from two different excels to fill in values to another column in the first excel.

I have two excel files:

| id | con_job | idContractor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | job1 |  |
| 2 | job2 |  |
| 3 | job2 |  |
| 4 | job3 |  |
| 5 |  |  |
| 6 | job5 |  |

The other excel file looks like this.

| id | job |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | job1 |
| 2 | job2 |
| 3 | job3 |
| 4 | job4 |
| 5 | job5 |
| 5 | job6 |

Some values might be missing.
What I want is to have idContractor filled with id from the first excel, so it looks like this:

| id | con_job | idContractor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | job1 | 1 |
| 2 | job2 | 2 |
| 3 | job2 | 2 |
| 4 | job3 | 3 |
| 5 |  |  |
| 6 | job5 | 6 |

I have been trying to create code that fills idContracor, but it doesn't work

```
df["idContractor"] = np.where(df["job"].isin(df2["con_job"]), df2['id'], "")

#I have also tried to do something like this, but I cannot make it work
df[df['con_job'] == df2['job'], df['idContractor']] = df2['id']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the Pandas [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function to do this. Here is how:

```
df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='con_job', right_on='job')
```

Comment: I have tried, but it doesn't populate the idContractor column.

Comment: You will have to rename the `id_left` column of the output to `idContractor`. This operation will not populate existing columns